# How to become productive in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to improve my Coffeescript coding style. When I program in Scala, I can write a module in an hour or two, run it and have only a few minor bugs that I can quickly identify and fix.

In Coffeescript, I spend about the same time up front but I end up having a staggering amount of small bugs that would have been caught by a static type checker and I end up having to compile, reload the browser, step through some code, add some break points, etc. It's an infuriating experience and takes significantly longer.

It's much harder to abstract and encapsulate functionality due to the lack of interfaces and many other OO-features.

Are there design patterns that replace the encapsulation/abstraction generally provided by OO? Or is there a primer/guide on how to think in a more Coffeescript-y way (or how to solve problems using a prototypical approach)?

What have you done to become more productive in Coffeescript (or Javascript - perhaps even any dynamically typed languages)?

Comment: It's not an answer, but to be productive in coffeescript, you really have to be very familiar with Javascript. If you're not, the debugging experience may really be a pain.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with both Javascript and Coffeescript - I can identify bugs based on application behaviour and I understand most of the weird parts of Javascript.

It's more that I keep making the same mistakes/bugs that I wouldn't in a statically typed language. I don't know whether adopting a particular coding style would help (which made the types clearer and made it harder to make simple typos and type errors) - but at the moment I can't believe this isn't something someone else has already solved.

Comment: Automated testing is crucial when working with dynamic languages. Having a good test suite is very helpful in catching errors when making potentially breaking changes to your application.

Answer (score 7):

If you're coming from a statically-typed, class-centric language like Java or Scala, learning JavaScript/CoffeeScript is going to be a challenge. The compiler doesn't help you nearly as much, which means that it takes you minutes to discover small mistakes instead of seconds.

If that's your major bottleneck, then I'd suggest embracing a more test-driven coding methodology. Use a library like [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) to write small tests for each piece of functionality you develop. Used properly, this style gives you the same benefits as a static compiler without compromising the flexibility of a dynamic language.

Comment: Sadly, not many people test JavaScript because historically the tools haven't been too great. Now there are great tools like QUnit and [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) which make testing JavaScript easy and even fun.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go straight to Coffee Script. Learn the core concepts from prototype and Javascript OO. IMMO You can learn both at the same time, but you will benefit much more if you get Vanilla Javascript first. Based on my personal experience, Coffee Script syntactic sugar for classes can be a trap if you don't understand prototypical inheritances (it's easy to get stuck on a bug).

Coffee Script debugging is still not a completely solved matter in terms of tools, the only way I know it can be done is to write tests (a pain when you're just starting) or look at the generated code (at least for the more obscure bugs).

Comment: Again - I understand Javascript and prototypical inheritance (and I'm not exactly a beginner with Coffeescript). 

It's more that I don't have a toolbelt of ways to approach problems with a prototyptical language (whereas I can quickly envisage a solution with classical oo).

Similarly, its more that I'm making simple mistakes that either the compiler or my IDE would typically catch - or would be clear because of type signatures. For example, is there a standard/good way of encoding types into function signatures (or even a standard way of documenting them)?

Answer (score 1):

It was odd for me too; in my case coming from a C/C++ background.

What clicked for me is that you can reduce your iteration time significantly with a few tweaks of your work environment. The idea is to reduce it enough that you can write code in small chunks and test your code very very frequently.

**On the lack of compile time checks:** You'll get used to it. Like significant white space, the lack of compile time type checking just melts away after a few weeks. It's hard to say how exactly, but at least I can tell you that it did happen for me.

**On the lack of interfaces:** that's a tricky one. It would be nice to get a little more help in larger systems to remind you to implement entire interfaces. If you're finding that you really are losing a lot of time to that, you could write your own run time checks, and insert them where appropriate. E.g. if you register your objects with a central manager, that would be a good time to ensure that the objects qualify for the role they're being submitted to.

In general, it's a good to bear in mind that you have decent reflection abilities to hand.

**On the lack of encapsulation**: Given that coffeescript implements a very nice class wrapper to the prototype scheme, I'm assuming you mean the lack of private variables? There are actually a number of ways you can hide details from clients, if you feel the need to, and I do; usually to stop myself from shooting my foot in the future. The key is usually to squirrel things away in closures.

Also, have a look at `Object.__defineGetter__` / `Object.defineProperty?` Getters and setter can help a lot in these situations.

**On reducing iteration time:**

I was using the built in file watcher in coffee to compile the scripts on change. Coupled with TextMate's ability to save all open files on losing focus, this meant that testing was a matter of switching from textmate to chrome/firefox and hitting refresh. Quite fast.

On a node.js project though, I've setup my views to just compile and serve on the fly so even the file watcher is superfluous. They're cached in release, but in the debug mode they're always reloaded from disk, recompiled, and on encountering errors I just serve them up instead. So now every few minutes I switch to the browser, hit refresh and either see my test running, or the compiler errors.